# Table name as a value in column

Tags: mysql

I got an exercise:

> Find names of companies in ascending order. The list should include
>   both supplier names and customer names. There should also be
>   information whether this company is supplier or customer.

It should look something like this:

```
CompanyName A, Supplier 
CompanytName B, Customer 
CompanyName C, Customer
```

What I have been able to do so far:

```
SELECT CompanyName 
FROM suppliers
UNION
SELECT CompanyName
FROM customers
ORDER BY CompanyName ASC;
```

So I am missing the information of whether the company is supplier or customer. Any help is welcome, thank you in advance and sorry for the bad title.

Comment: you can return constants in select statements, `select 1 from a` will return 1 repeated for every row in a

Comment: if you can, please share you table structure

Comment: add the data (column names and values contained in them) contained in tables to the question please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think depending on the structure of the database tables that you might want to consider JOIN, but if you need to use UNION I would add the following to each table SELECT like the following:

```
SELECT CompanyName, 'Supplier'
FROM suppliers
UNION
SELECT CompanyName, 'Customers'
FROM customers
ORDER BY CompanyName ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just select a literal value in each statement like so:

```
SELECT CompanyName, 'Supplier' AS Type
FROM suppliers
UNION
SELECT CompanyName, 'Customer'
FROM customers
ORDER BY CompanyName ASC;
```

Then you will have the result set you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I didn't figure this out myself, I tried something much more complicated.